# Action renders View of the first called Action (when an Action calls another Action)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The name is pretty confusing probably. I have a requirement where a URL must be name friendly to represent dates (`schedule/today`, `schedule/tomorrow` etc). I *don't* want to clutter my route mappings with `DateTime.Now`, `DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)` etc for different parameters so I decided to create routes that map to an action of the same name:

```
routes.MapRoute(RouteNames.ScheduleToday, "schedule/today", new { controller = "Schedule", action = "Today" });
routes.MapRoute(RouteNames.ScheduleTomorrow, "schedule/tomorrow", new { controller = "Schedule", action = "Tomorrow" });
```

The idea for the actions is that I'd like to be able to call the `Today()` action but actually call the `List(DateTime date)` action with, for example, `DateTime.Now` as the `date` parameter.

This works great like this:

```
public ActionResult Today()
{
    return this.List(DateTime.Now);
}

public ViewResult List(DateTime date)
{
    this.ViewData["Date"] = date;
    return this.View("List");
}
```

I'd like to be able to call `this.View()` instead of `this.View("List")`. Is this possible other than what I've posted above? It seems as though the view that is rendered matches the name of the *first* action that is called since the only way to get this to work is to explicitly render the `List` view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still can't find *why* the first action that is called matches the view and not the *last* action (perhaps I'll dig into the source). For the time being I'll stick with what I have since there's no reason to over-complicate things.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to make the parameterless View() return a view other than the one that matches the name of the first action method. But what about this approach to solve your issue *without* putting DateTime.Now in your route mappings - if you define your route mappings like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(RouteNames.ScheduleToday, "schedule/today", new { controller = "Schedule", action = "List", identifier = "today" });
routes.MapRoute(RouteNames.ScheduleTomorrow, "schedule/tomorrow", new { controller = "Schedule", action = "List", identifier = "tomorrow" });
```

Here we've introduced a new route token called "identifier" which matches what you have in the route. The other thing you could do is define a *single* route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(RouteNames.ScheduleToday, "schedule/{identifier}", new { controller = "Schedule", action = "List" });
```

But in that case, you'd want a route constraint to constrain your {identifier} token to only your valid values that you support.  With these routes in place, you can simply create a custom ActionFilterAttribute which **has the single responsibility for setting up dates**.

Something like this:

```
public class DateSelectorAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var identifier = filterContext.RouteData.Values["identifier"] as string;
        switch (identifier)
        {
            case "today":
                filterContext.ActionParameters["date"] = DateTime.Now;
                break;
            case "tomorrow":
                filterContext.ActionParameters["date"] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now your List() method can just look like this:

```
[DateSelector]
public ActionResult List(DateTime date)
{
    this.ViewData.Model = date;
    return this.View();
}
```

And as a side note, I realized setting up the DateTime.Now in the routes wouldn't work anyway because that would only get called at application start up, effectively caching the date values. The action filter is a better approach because it gets called real-time and gives you the accurate date.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the idea but I think it's really over-complicating what needs to be done. Calling the `this.View("List")` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is wrong in the way you redirect to another controller action from `Today()`. You should be using one of the `RedirectToAction()` overloads. That way you won't have to specify a View in the `List()` action. And you can provide DateTime as a route value to `RedirectToAction()`.

Comment: Yeah I tried that too but the problem is that it'll actually redirect the URL as well and will put the date *in* the URL (which is ugly since I want to keep them friendly).